# A safe way to send and show passwords to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, encryption, passwords

I'm building a password manager site using nodejs on the back end. When the user registers and saves a password I encrypt it and then store it in the db, so it's safe. The problem is that I need a safe way to send it from the database and show it to the user when needed. Which is the best way, send it encrypted to the client and decrypt it with a script or decrypt on the back end before sending it? Is https safe enough to protect requests and responses?

Comment: If somebody is able to read your HTTPS traffic then they have already had the opportunity to steal the users master login password. Encrypting the password sent back to the client seems pointless at this point.

Comment: To be honest, HTTPS is going to be way more secure and scrutinized compared to your pw manager's implementation or maybe your DB/OS patch level, so you should be more concerned about them then HTTPS itself.

Comment: If the backend ever gets to see the password it's not safe, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try encrypt and decrypt at device level, so the only risk you take is getting the master password. A good way to do that is with: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html.

With FS can you write and read data from device level

Answer (score 0):

When making decisions about cryptography, ask two essential questions:

- What is your threat model?
- Should you be implementing it yourself or use an existing solution (such as BitWarden, an open-source password manager)?

Your seemingly-simple question is tricky, because Web security in general is a complex topic. In an application such as yours, several layers are involved, and you must decide what to do about each of them in your threat model:

- Client/browser
- Front-end server
- Back-end server (can be the same as the front-end server depending on architecture)
- Database

Depending on who controls what, the answers will be different. For example, if you're developing a password manager to be deployed on a company's premises, then it likely won't matter whether you encrypt/decrypt on the "back-end" or on the "front-end", as they'll usually end up being the same host, managed by the same IT people. A compromise of the host can result in injecting malicious code, which can then intercept all passwords, keys, etc. right there in the browser, and it's little help that all crypto is done on the client when the client-side code is controlled by the attacker.

In such cases, what will matter more is policy decisions - e.g. if the passwords sometimes  safeguard GDPR-subjected personal records, you may need to implement the principle of least privilege and make the journey of the plaintext passwords as short as possible - whether a server-hosted "site" can ever accomplish this becomes an organizational/legal question, rather than a technical one.

Analyze your threat model carefully - what attack scenarios are you defending against? Do different people own the DB layer and the back-end servers, or could a single person dump all DB data and undetectably replace the client-side JS? What do your defenses protect - data at rest, data in transit? You might find that, depending on your desired security properties, a Web-based password manager is not feasible. On the other hand, it may be that you're after simple, single-tier deployments, in which case your job is easier as you can do crypto on the back-end.

The least you could do, if you decide to roll your own password manager, is to look at existing software and learn from it. Pick something that has been audited (e.g. Bitwarden!), find the audit document, see what pitfalls the original authors had run into.

Comment: Thank you. What are your thoughts about what I asked to Eric?

Comment: @matteo you wrote that you're using bcrypt for encryption, but it's a password-hashing function. Not sure how that relates to storing recoverable passwords. If you mean the "access password" that is necessary as an authorization step to download the encrypted data, then no - bcrypt is no longer recommended. See: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: I will jump here to avoid two discussion threads. Yes problem is it's a hashing algo not encryption, so you can use it for "encrypting" pw in vault.

Comment: For argon2, I have heard it before but didn't know it it's the now recommended way. However, I would argue "bcrypt is no longer recommended" is a little overstatement. Though it's not on the #1 on _that_ list, it is still #2, with 20+ yrs age and battle tested.

Comment: So depends on the situation, bcrypt could still be a good choice

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is extremely scrutinized that you can assume it's safe, so long you can keep openssl on your system updated. And honestly, your password manager's implementation or maybe your DB/OS patch level is more likely be vulnerable to attacks.

But to answer your question. In theory, decrypting on client side could be safer, but that is only if the decryption truly happens on client side, and that the decryption key is never transmitted over the wire.

That way, even if somebody else gains access to the data or taps data in transit (even with HTTPS decrypted), they will not be able to decrypt it because they will not get the decryption key.

Afterall, that is basically end-to-end encryption like some messaging app does, just in asynchronous fashion.

And why not ask how others do it if you are doing it. For example, 1Password actually built their own protocol called [Secure Remote Password (SRP)](https://support.1password.com/secure-remote-password/) and they published a [white paper](https://1password.com/files/1Password-White-Paper.pdf) detailing the exact intricacies. So you can definitely take reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At the moment I'm using bcrypt for encryption. Do you know if it's ok or there is a better library?